# Pandas - save multiple CSV in a zip archive

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv, zip

I need to save multiple dataframes in CSV, all in a same zip file.
Is it possible without making temporary files?

I tried using zipfile:

```py
with zipfile.ZipFile("archive.zip", "w") as zf:
    with zf.open(f"file1.csv", "w") as buffer:
        data_frame.to_csv(buffer, mode="wb")
```

This works with `to_excel` but fails with `to_csv` as as zipfiles expects binary data and `to_csv` writes a string, despite the `mode="wb"` parameter:

> .../lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py", line 283, in _save_header
>
> writer.writerow(encoded_labels)
>
> .../lib/python3.8/zipfile.py", line 1137, in write
>
> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

On the other hand, I tried using the `compression` parameter of `to_csv`, but the archive is overwritten, and only the last dataframe remains in the final archive.

If no other way, I'll use temporary files, but I was wondering if someone have an idea to allow `to_csv` and `zipfile` work together.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would approach this following way

```
import io
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":[1,2,3]})
string_io = io.StringIO()
df.to_csv(string_io)
string_io.seek(0)
df_bytes = string_io.read().encode('utf-8')
```

as `df_bytes` is bytes it should now work with `zipfile`. Edit: after looking into `to_csv` help I found simpler way, to get `bytes` namely:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":[1,2,3]})
df_bytes = df.to_csv().encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: @EinoGourdin I found simpler way after consulting help of to_csv and edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 2):

For saving multiple excel files from dataframe in a zip file

```
import zipfile
from zipfile import ZipFile
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"x":[1,2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"y":[4,5,6]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"z":[7,8,9]})

with zipfile.ZipFile("rishabh.zip", "w") as zf:
      with zf.open(f"check1.xlsx", "w") as buffer:
         df1.to_excel(buffer,index=False)
      with zf.open(f"check2.xlsx", "w") as buffer:
         df2.to_excel(buffer,index=False)
      with zf.open(f"check3.xlsx", "w") as buffer:
         df3.to_excel(buffer, index=False)
```